# Remove everything to right of 3rd "." in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to trim down IP addresses in Excel and need to remove everything to the right of the third "." in each string.

For example, "217.198.108.207" would become "217.198.108".

Tried the `=LEFT()` function but the number of characters before the third "." varies each time.

I can't figure it out, is there a function for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume that your column is **A1**. Using **LEFT()** and **FIND()** you can accomplish what you need, like:

```
=LEFT(A1;FIND(".";A1;FIND(".";A1;FIND(".";A1)+1)+1)-1)
```

**FIND()** function takes three parameters. Third, while optional, is actually an offset where to start search. So, first **FIND()** finds the first dot, moves right by one, and passes that number into second **FIND()**. Second **FIND()** finds the first dot after the first dot (to say so), which means it finds second dot and moves one character to the right.

This number is finally passed to the third **FIND()**, which then basically finds first dot after the second dot, which is, obviously, the third dot.

Finally, position of the third dot minus one character (because you do not need the third dot) is passed to **LEFT()** function, which returns what you need.

Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this (value in K1):

```
=LEFT(K1;FIND("#";SUBSTITUTE(K1;".";"#";3))-1)
```

In this case you say, in the last argument of SUBSTITUTE, the dot you want to replace and will be more versatile